# Reactive Forms: Multiselect

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am very new to reactive forms so I do not have a clue how to do what I want.

I have an Observable where I get the following data:

```
AllUsers: [
    {
        User_ID: "xxxA",
        User_Name: "AAAA"
    },
    {
        User_ID: "xxxB",
        User_Name: "BBBB"
    },
    {
        User_ID: "xxxC",
        User_Name: "CCCC"
    }
]

ProductsBoughtBy: [
    {
        Product: {
            Product_ID: "xaxa",
            Product_Name: "Product 1",
            Version: 2
        },
        UsersBought: [
            {
                User_ID: "xxxA",
                User_Name: "AAAA"
            },
            {
                User_ID: "xxxB",
                User_Name: "BBBB"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Product: {
            Product_ID: "xbxb",
            Product_Name: "Product 2",
            Version: 4
        },
        UsersBought: [
            {
                User_ID: "xxxA",
                User_Name: "AAAA"
            },
            {
                User_ID: "xxxC",
                User_Name: "CCCC"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the html I use ngx-table to show a table with 3 Column. The First one is used for Product Name, the second for Product version and the third for a multiselect from angular material, where all users are listed and the users from the ProductsBoughtBy are checked per default.

But I do not understand how to create my ?FormsArray? or do I need the FormsGroup. And how to bind it to the html mat-select.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import the necessary modules in your component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
```

Create a FormGroup and FormArray in your component class

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  usersArray: FormArray;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      products: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

    this.usersArray = this.formBuilder.array([]);
    this.form.addControl('users', this.usersArray);
  }
}
```

now populate the form with your data

```
data$.subscribe(data => {
  const productsArray = this.form.get('products') as FormArray;

  data.ProductsBoughtBy.forEach(product => {
    const productGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: product.Product.Product_Name,
      version: product.Product.Version,
      users: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

    product.UsersBought.forEach(user => {
      const userGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: user.User_ID,
        name: user.User_Name
      });

      (productGroup.get('users') as FormArray).push(userGroup);
    });

    productsArray.push(productGroup);
  });
});
```

Now bind the form controls to your HTML template using the formGroup directive and the formArrayName directive

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="products">
    <div *ngFor="let product of form.get('products').controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div>{{ product.get('name').value }}</div>
      <div>{{ product.get('version').value }}</div>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Users</mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControlName]="'users'" multiple>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let user of product.get('users').controls; let j = index" [value]="user.get('id').value">
            {{ user.get('name').value }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

hope it's helpful